# Can different cell lines of same type symbolise samples from different patients in ChIP-seq?

Tags: molecular-genetics, human-genetics, chip-seq

Can I simulate different patients by using different cell lines of the same cell type and from the same tissue? Can I also study apoptosis in an immortalised cell line?

I have a gene X (transcription factor) which from wet lab experiments induces apoptosis in  cell type A (endothelial cells) and proliferation in cell type B (smooth muscle cells).

I want to address this differential behaviour using ChIP-seq of antibodies against gene X.

I do not have enough patient samples and I wish to purchase immortalised cell lines to perform ChIP-seq with 4 biological replicates per condition: untreated control and over expression of X.

I plan each biological replicate to be a different cell line of the same cell type and preferably the same tissue. Is it possible to have such?

I will also be very grateful if anyone provides me a link or good article containing the best practices in planning for a ChIP-seq experiment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to say anything conclusively unless we know what kind of cells you are talking about.

Comment: @ WYSIWYG Thank you for your response. I will use microvascular endothelial cells from the skin and or lungs.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add this information? And do you plan to use cell lines like lung/skin cancer as a proxy?

Comment: @WYSIWYG  Please I am completely new to Chip-seq and I do not properly understand the meaning of "proxy" in this context. But I think I will only be using non-cancerous cell lines from the skin or the lungs.

Comment: I used "proxy" in a general sense. Using something in place of the other (a substitute that is expected to represent the original condition). In your case, the cell lines being proxy for the patient samples. There are commercially available human microvascular endothelial cells. Are you planning to use them?

Comment: Again, I would point out that it would be difficult to say anything conclusively unless we know what the patients really suffer from and whether the experimental model replicates these disease conditions accurately. A general answer would most probably be "no" as we can expect that most cell lines would not properly represent the actual condition. In some cases, however, the cell lines can be a good model. So, as I said before, it is difficult to comment without knowing more details.

Comment: @WYSIWYG  Thanks a lot for your response. Yes I plan to use commercially available human microvascular endothelial cells from the skin or the lung. Could you please recommend for me a link  or links where I could find such cells? I need 5 different human skin microvascular cellines  per treatment condition (untreated and overexpressed). I have been searching the internet but I cannot find the number I want.

Comment: Moreover, I think you are asking multiple questions here. First is whether cell lines represent the patient conditions reasonably well. Second is whether different cell lines derived from the same tissue are more or less similar (and if they are available commercially or otherwise). The last part about ChIP-seq guidelines is somewhat off-topic. There are plenty of articles available on this topic.

Comment: Regarding purchasing the cells: I have no experience on this topic but google gives me many hits to vendor websites: Lonza, Thermo and some other smaller companies.

Comment: @WYSIWYG  Thanks a lot for your elaborations. In addition to having a better understanding, You answered all my questions.